# PDO: Using fetchAll on unknown query

Tags: php, pdo

I have a php class that I use to run SQL statements via PDO. The class stores the FetchAll's data to that query in a public variable But the problem is that I don't know what the query will be so I end up calling FetchAll on data manipulation queries (INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE)

how can I know if a particular query is fetchable or not? I don't want to use hacks like checking if the query starts from INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE.

```
class mysql {
    public $call, $rows;
    public function query($a) {
        $this->call = $pdo->prepare($a['query']);
        foreach($a['params'] as $key => $param) {$this->call->bindValue($key + 1, $param);}
        $this->rows = $this->call->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}
```

This throws error if I run a manipulation query.

Edit: complete class

```
class mysql {
    public $call, $rows;

    // allows query on construct time
    function __construct($a = false) {if($a) $this->query($a);}
    public function query($a) {
        $this->call = $pdo->prepare($a['query']);

        // execute the query with or without parameters, and if it succeeds and dontLog is not set and the query has data manipulation then call the log function to log the query along with user id
        if($this->call->execute(isset($a['params']) ? $a['params'] : null) && !isset($a['dontLog']) && in_array(substr($a['query'], 0, 6), array('INSERT','UPDATE','DELETE'))) $this->log(isset($a['params']) ? json_encode($a['params']) : '');

        // if the call returns any columns then store it in rows public variable or store an empty array
        $this->rows = ($this->call->columnCount() > 0) ? $this->call->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) : array();
    }
    private function log($params) {
        new mysql(array('query' => 'INSERT INTO logs (user, query, parameters) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', 'params' => array($GLOBALS['user']['id'], $this->call->queryString, $params), 'dontLog' => true));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use [PDOStatement::columnCount](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.columncount.php)

Comment: Ok that was rather simple. Thanks! No Idea why google didn't turn that up for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's a class!

Why have only single method as tough it's just an ordinary function?
Why return FetchAll all the time? there can be scalar returned which going to be very handy. Or a single row?
Why not to have separate methods for different results?

- fetchall for the rows
- fetchrow for the row
- fetchone for the scalar
- query for the everything else

it would be extremely handy and **readable**

Also, you have to change this strange code

```
foreach($a['params'] as $key => $param) {$this->call->bindValue($key + 1, $param);}
```

to this one

```
$this->call->execute($a['params']);
```

as your current code plainly unworkable.

Or, to make it really handy

```
public function fetchAll($a)
{
    $params = func_get_args();
    $query = array_shift($args);
    $this->call = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $this->call->execute($params);
    return $this->call->fetchAll();
}
```

to be called like this:

```
$rows = $db->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM t WHERE cat=?",$catagory);
```

neat, eh?

one more - you have to return the result, not store it in a class variable. Your class don't need these rows but calling code does.

Comment: I made it a class because it allows me to store result and query reference with each object. So I can make multiple `mysql` objects on single page and be able to reference the execute()'s reference. For example, to add one row multiple times, I just have to call `execute()` on the public `call` variable. I can't do that with fetchAll function you wrote. It gives flexibility. And there are other functions that I removed. A logging function that logs the query along with user info to map what user made what changes. And as for why always fetchAll then the output has to be consistent.

Comment: `row` variable always has the array of returned rows, be it 0, 1 or n. I need to store the rows because my mysql call are usually global and i don't need to keep passing the result array to any function i use, i can simply reference the object and then get the stored `row` variable. Saves memory by not copying huge result arrays b/w function scopes and using PHP's built in practice of using pointers for passed object's properties. And thanks for bindParam, I will update it. :)

Comment: Also as It turns out, I can't use the bindParams code. There is more code, I will post the complete class in the question.